# How to interpret when there are many "for"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Operator for new marinas in A and existing B
>   marinas **for** boats

Which meaning is correct for the sentence above?

Operator for (new marinas in A for boats) and (existing B marinas for boats)

or

Operator for (new marinas in A) and (existing B marinas for boats)

Comment: maybe this doesn't matter, but what are A and B? the names of towns? put in fake town names instead? Then the sentence doesn't flow particularly well "existing San Diego marinas for boats"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sentence is, as you observe, ambiguous. It could be disambiguated with commas.

> Operator for new marinas in A, and existing B marinas, for boats.

That corresponds with your first parse.

> Operator for new marinas in A, and existing B marinas for boats.

That may still be read as ambiguous, but is more pointing towards your second parse.

Comment: I don't think the commas really serve to disambiguate the two meanings that clearly in your examples. What about *operator for new boat marinas in A and existing ones in B*? I don't know if *boat marina* is a thing. If it is, you could also say *operator for new marinas in A and existing boat marinas in B* to express the other meaning.

Comment: I'm very confident that the two-comma version removes the ambiguity. The one-comma version, not do much. You can disambiguate *better* by rephrasing, but the question is about what the given sentence means, so sentences that are very different wouldn't seem to be actually addressing the question.

Comment: Of course, only using the second comma and not the first would also remove that ambiguity.